# Cannot send an email with python smtp

Tags: python, smtp

I am developing an application using python where I need to send a file through mail. I wrote a program to send the mail but dont know there's something wrong. The code is posted below. Please any one help me with this smtp library. Is there's anything i m missing? And also can someone please tell me what will be the host in smtp! I am using smtp.gmail.com.
Also can any one tell me how can i email a file (.csv file). Thanks for the help!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib

sender = 'someone@yahoo.com'
receivers = ['someone@yahoo.com']

message = """From: From Person <someone@yahoo.com>
To: To Person <someone@yahoo.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Successfully sent email"
except:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

Comment: Please provide the error details.

Comment: Tichodroma, Lafada, :
socket.error:[Errno 10060] A connectoin attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't logging in. There are also a couple reasons you might not make it through including blocking by your ISP, gmail bouncing you if it can't get a reverse DNS on you, etc.

```
try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) # or 465
   smtpObj.ehlo()
   smtpObj.starttls()
   smtpObj.login(account, password)
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Successfully sent email"
except:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

I just noticed your request to be able to attach a file. That changes things since now you need to deal with encoding. Still not that tough to follow though I don't think.

```
import os
import email
import email.encoders
import email.mime.text
import smtplib

# message/email details
my_email = 'myemail@gmail.com'
my_passw = 'asecret!'
recipients = ['jack@gmail.com', 'jill@gmail.com']
subject = 'This is an email'
message = 'This is the body of the email.'
file_name = 'C:\\temp\\test.txt'

# build the message
msg = email.MIMEMultipart.MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = my_email
msg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)
msg['Date'] = email.Utils.formatdate(localtime=True)
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg.attach(email.MIMEText.MIMEText(message))

# build the attachment
att = email.MIMEBase.MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
att.set_payload(open(file_name, 'rb').read())
email.Encoders.encode_base64(att)
att.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(file_name))
msg.attach(att)

# send the message
srv = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
srv.ehlo()
srv.starttls()
srv.login(my_email, my_passw)
srv.sendmail(my_email, recipients, msg.as_string())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried this but i got a error that username and password not accepted. I have little confusion on login(account,password). what that account meant. Is that a sender mail account or something else.

Comment: account is the gmail account (myemail@gmail.com) you want to send the email from and password is the password for that account. I just noticed your attachment request. Will update my answer with that shortly.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Will you please post your update as soon as possible... (:

Comment: Oh and so you know if this is a free account and sends a decent amount of email gmail will probably block it from sending. A real pain and no real logic to it but I've seen it enough times to not use gmail for anything but testing. Pay accounts through gmail don't have that problem though and are very reliable.